# Do i need the Facebook PHP SDK for Page Tab Apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I'm developing a Facebook Page Tab App. The files are located on my own server and i've created a Facebook App.

Now i'm trying to access the user's first name and i found different ways to get user informations, e.g. the `$signedrequest` (for the user ID) or the Facebook PHP SDK.

So do i need the SDK, e.g. for Graph API calls, or are there other ways to get informations from Facebook in my Page Tab App?

Using the SDK i get a lot of errors like `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.`, even if the user is already logged in.

Comment: Of course you can make API requests yourself (with basically any technology that can make HTTP requests to remote servers) - but using the PHP SDK usually simplifies the whole thing a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user have not signed in to your app you will not get the user name or user id from the singend request parameter. It will give you information if the user likes the page, is admin of the page and additional app_data.

Using the php-sdk you can use the getLoginUrl() method, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/, to get the access token needed to fetch user name, user id etc.